# Is there a way to enable search queries while serving a custom html via a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

So, I wanna send some data while serving a html file. The thing is, I'm trying to change the website DOM they're visiting to have a button that redirects them to my custom html page.

Something like this:

```
let baseUrl = chrome.extension.getURL("html/index.html");
const newLink = `<a target="_blank" href="${baseUrl}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-play"></i></a>`;
```

This is working fine. But I also want to send some data to that html. I thought maybe I could pass that data as a query to the URL.

something like `${baseUrl}&data=hello`

But this didn't work. It showed:

> gicmcddpcghcleckoponopgdnbffjpel is blocked. Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.
> Try disabling your extensions.
> ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

So, is there a way to enable this? Or am I doing this wrong completely and there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Replace `&` with `?`

Comment: huh? oh no! why? why did i write `&` instead of `?` lol, anyway thanks